# in /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib, missing required architecture armv6

Tags: ios

In attempting to compile a dummy program for iphoneos, Xcode4, gcc does not appear to reach beyond the initial sysroot directory

```
$ echo $ISYSROOT
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
$ gcc -arch armv6 --sysroot=$ISYSROOT  test.cpp
ld: in /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib, missing required architecture armv6 in file for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I leave out sysroot,

```
$ gcc -arch armv6  test.cpp
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/crt1.o, missing required architecture armv6 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib, missing required architecture armv6 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture armv6 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The following works, but it feels very cheesy, and not scalable. What's going on here?

```
$ gcc -arch armv6  -L$ISYSROOT/usr/lib/system --sysroot=$ISYSROOT  test.cpp
```

**Update.** Apparently this is a known issue, though it still is not clear how to pass sysroot to gcc but isysroot to ld

http://www.doitscared.com/?m=201104

> When compiling the library, if you see this error “ld: file not found:
>   /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture armv7″, then your
>   linker command is using “–sysroot” which doesn’t work in Xcode 4.
>   Instead, change the linker command to use “-isysroot”. (Note: This
>   only applies to the linker command. The compile commands must continue
>   to use “–sysroot”. See here for more details.)

Comment: thanks! $ gcc -arch armv6  -L$ISYSROOT/usr/lib/system --sysroot=$ISYSROOT  test.cpp did help me!

Answer (score 0):

Change the Deployment Target of your project to be at least 4.3 and it will work.  This is a problem with XCode 4 but there really isn't a need to deploy apps to iOS versions prior to 4.3.  iOS users tend to stay pretty up-to-date with their iOS versions.

Comment: I'm stuck on 4.2.1 with an old iOS device that cannot upgrade past that point - I just wanted to compile ncurses for it. Thanks for nothing.